# Fortran file I/O 2D array

Tags: io, fortran

File to be read into program is a .txt, call it `numbers.txt`, of the form

```
75694
13265
98654
```

and I want to read each single digit into a rank-2 array (so the array shape is [3 5]).  The problem with my methods seems to be advancing to a new record, and me not having a good understanding of implied DOs:

```
program f3
  implicit none
  integer, dimension(3,5) :: arr
  integer :: i, j
  open(unit=15,file="numbers.txt")

  ! Only attempting one method at a time, so one will be commented.                                                                              

  !----- Method 1 - how to advance to next record? -----                                                                                         
  do i=1,3
     do j=1,5
        read(unit=15, fmt='(I1)', advance="no") arr(i,j)
     enddo
  enddo


  !----- Method 2 - get "end of file" error -----                                                                                                
  do i=1,3
     read(unit=15, fmt='(I1)', advance="no") (arr(i,j), j=1,5)
  enddo

  close(15)

  ! Best way to display 2D array?                                                                                                                 
  write(6,'(5I1)') ((arr(i,j), j=1,5), i=1,3)

end program f3
```

I'd like to be able to use do loops, implied do loops, or a combination of them just to get a better feel for their operations, but if there is one "standard" method to do this I'd like to know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing this

```
  do i=1,3
     do j=1,5
        read(unit=15, fmt='(I1)', advance="no") arr(i,j)
     enddo
  enddo
```

with this

```
  do i=1,3
        read(unit=15, fmt='(5I1)') arr(i,:)
  enddo
```

That should get you going.

And for writing:

```
  do ix = 1,3
     write(*,'(5(i1,1x))') arr(ix,:)
  end do
```

is an approach I might take.

Comment: Totally personal and off-topic, but I usually go with e.g. `5(1x,i1)` because I hate trailing blanks.

Comment: @steabert Or `5(I1,:,1X)`.

Comment: @francescalus what does the ':' do?

Comment: @KyleG It's the _colon edit descriptor_.  In short, it terminates the output when there are no more items to output (before the final `1X` in this example).  A complication far too far for this answer, though.

Comment: or even just `5I2` for a simple case like this one